# VAT price and price without VAT in cart

Tags: price, vat

i need display 2 price in cart price with VAT and price without VAT - next row, please let me know how i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System->Configuration->Tax->Shopping Cart Display Settings` and set the field `Display Prices` to `Including and excluding tax`.

Answer (score 1):

Not working, i need display in cart in total box next:

> Total: 591,84 €*
>
> Shipping: 39,95 €*
>
> Total 631,79 €
>
> Total without VAT.: 530,91 €
>
> VAT.: 100,88 €